# Peltier stopped working

Tags: peltier, cooling

I am creating a sort of food cooler using a tec1-12706 peltier element since i figured the casing where the food goes in is already made of an heat/cold conductive metal. The cold side was not attached yet and the hot side was attached using only a big pea size of thermal paste to a cooler maser hyper h412r. I ran it for about 10 to 15 minutes feeling the cold side and the hot side by the cooler. The cooler got slightly warm but really not that much. After i turned the power off and left for about 2 hours i wanted to test it again but it wast not getting cool on one side and warm on the other side. For the power i wass using a 12v 100w meanwell led power supply. With both the fan of the heatsink and the peltier attatched to it.

Was it to loosely attached to the heatsink and so overheated or what else could have happend

Comment: Did you measure that power supply was actually outputing 12V and the voltage ended up to the TEC?

Comment: Yes, i measured the output voltage before i hooked it up and i corrected it to 12V

Comment: So you did not check after when it was connected, so you don't know if the power supply shut down when connecting the load.